# why Web Application Projects have designer.cs files and web site not in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

**i want to know why Web Application Projects have designer.cs files  and web site not in asp.net**

like this

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace JavaScript
{


    public partial class WebForm1
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// form1 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because web site "projects" are designed to be simple-minded.

Comment: i read this article but i have no answer why designer.cs files in web application

Comment: Wrong question. Why no .designer.cs files in web site "projects". Because they are simple-minded.